# How to resize partition on new installation to make room for additional OS?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4

I did a complete reinstall today of Ubuntu 16.04 (my SSD was encrypted, which prevented me from resizing the partition. This got old, and I didn't feel like going through the command line mess to get rid of it and possibly messing up). I have another Linux distro that I've been using via Live Persistent USB, but it's simply too slow, so I want to put it on my hard drive.

Here are my partitions:

[image: Ubuntu Partitions]

I obviously can't unmount sda2 while it's running, so how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that you try to resize system **sda** and system is running.

**To solve that**:

1. Make bootable usb and boot .
2. Instead of **install** -> **try ubuntu** .
3. Open ***gparted*** installed by default and resize.

Comment: He said his SSD was encrypted, so this would not work unless he has a self-encrypting drive which the BIOS asks you to unlock at boot time even if it isn't booting from the SSD.

Comment: @insert_name_here i have also SSD encrypted and i do the same

Comment: @insert_name_here It's no longer encrypted. I completely wiped my OS and restarted with a fresh new (unencrypted) distro. I'll try the live boot/gparted thing, and come back to accept the answer. :)

Comment: @MohamedSlama Do I need to reinstall after doing this?

Comment: @IRGeekSauce no

Comment: hope you good luck :)

Comment: @MohamedSlama And done. Thanks! I know what to do in the future now. Now I just need to figure out how to add the second OS.